# Objective-C How to maintain initial value inside block, when capturing a variable with a __block modifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, static-variables

**Updated Question** I made the situation clearer, so you "need to" have access the original value from within the block.

I don't know if the following code serves any practical purpose, but just for the sake of learning and experimenting, consider the following:

```
__block int one = 1;
int(^capture)() = ^{
    int copiedOne = one;    // Copy one
    ++one;  // Add one
    return copiedOne;
};
NSLog(@"one: %i", one);  // one = 1
NSLog(@"copied one: %i", capture());  // Returns copiedOne = 1, one is now 2
NSLog(@"one after calling block: %i", one); // one = 2

one += 10;  // one = 12

NSLog(@"one: %i", one);  // Prints 12
NSLog(@"copied one: %i", capture());  // Returns copiedOne = 12, one is now 13
NSLog(@"one after calling block: %i", one); // one = 13
```

If you wanted to hold on to the very initial value 1 within the block, but also be able to modify `one` inside the block (I don't know. Maybe one day you might need this behavior), is there another way than to have a the value encapsulated in a static `NSNumber` variable like the following?

This behavior might be needed if `one` was a private property of an instance of `ClassA`, but you need an instance of `ClassB` to update the property of `ClassA` instance while getting the original value of `one`. You could call the `capture` from `ClassB` and achieve the above-mentioned behavior, while still gaining access to the original value of property `one` of `ClassA`.

```
__block int one = 1;
int(^capture)() = ^{
    static NSNumber *copiedOne = nil;
    if (!copiedOne) {
        copiedOne = @(one);    // Copy one
    }
    ++one;  // Add one
    return [copiedOne intValue];
};
NSLog(@"one: %i", one);  // one = 1
NSLog(@"copied one: %i", capture());  // Returns copiedOne = 1, one is now 2
NSLog(@"one after calling block: %i", one); // one = 2

one += 10;  // one = 12

NSLog(@"one: %i", one);  // Prints 12
NSLog(@"copied one: %i", capture());  // Returns copiedOne = 1, one is now 13
NSLog(@"one after calling block: %i", one); // one = 13
```

Comment: block copy the `one` at where the block defined. `static NSNumber *copiedOne` make the code 'copy one' only execute one time. It has the similar mechanism in my answer which keep the value just before block defined and keep the value outside the block to make the copy operation only execute one time.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess that makes sense. As long as you have the original value, who cares if you copied directly from the property itself or a copy of the property.

Answer (score 0):

The block captures any values of variables that are declared around it, whether or not you use the __block declaration.  The __block declaration allows you to change the value inside that variable.  It essentially changes how the block itself sees that variable, without __block declaration it would be considered static to the block.

So it would make sense that you would leave that initial one variable as is and not declare it __block.  And then make a copy of that variable before creating the block and make that the one that you want to modify.

```
int one = 1;
__block copiedOne = one;
void(^capture)() = ^{
     ++CopiedOne;  // Add one
     NSLog(@"copiedOne: %i, one: %i", copiedOne, one);
};
```

From Apple Docs...

> Because an Integer is declared as a __block variable, its storage is shared with the block declaration.

[Link to docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)